# Integer Operation Without Overflow Check

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx, integer-overflow, secure-coding

Hi I just ran a static code analysis on my code and I keep getting the error

> "Integer Operation Without Overflow Check"

Can someone help me resolve this or tell me what it means exactly. I have already tried to using the check keywords to fix this but it still came up when I ran the code.

```
List<String> emailList = new List<string>();

if (tbRecipients.Text.Contains(','))
{
    string[] splits = tbRecipients.Text.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
    {
        if (splits[i].Contains(';'))
        {
            emailList.AddRange(splits[i].Split(';').ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            emailList.Add(splits[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbRecipients"  runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What tool are you using to make the analysis? Does it points to a line in particular or just the whole block of code?

Comment: VCG and yes it points to this line for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)

Answer (score 3):

The message you get says that you could get an "overflow" on an `int`, that's because `int`s in `C#` are `32 bit` so that you can only store in it numbers lower than `2^31`. So *VCG* tell you that while doing several `i++` you could end up with an `i = 2^31` which would overflow your `int` and yield unexpected code behavior.

This could only happen in your code in the case that `splitted.Length == int.MaxValue` since `splitted` is an *array* and the `Length` property is `int`, so when you get `i == int.MaxLength` the loop will evaluate `i == splitted.Length` and will go to `i++` which would overflow.

However your loop says `i < splitted.Length` so that `i == splitted.Length` **won't** happen.

Bottom line: I think *VCG* has spotted a suspicious line, but there is nothing to worry about.
Hope this helps, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

> I have already tried to using the check keywords to fix this

The first step would be to understand the message. Making random code changes it not a good way to deal with possible bugs that are reported to you.

Here, there is no possible integer overflow. Hard to say more without details about the tool.